# Installing ROS on pcDuino (Lubuntu 12.04 ARM)

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, beagleboard, ros, pandaboard

Last week, I've purchased a pcDuino. It comes with Lubuntu v12.04. In order to download, compile, and install ROS; I'm following the documentation of Pandaboard from this link http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/PandaBoard/Source .

However, when I try to install the remaining dependencies with the

```
 sudo rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro groovy -y
```

command.
It gives an error that says "Could Not Detect OS: tried windows,ubuntu,...." I don't know if it's because of the reason that pcDuino uses Lubuntu.
I've searched about this error but there is no certain answer that I've understood.

Also I've stumbled onto that link (http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/UbuntuARM) that describes installing groovy on Ubuntu ARM, but you should download every package -that I don't have which to download- individually.

It would be appreciated if anybody can help me solve this problem or tell me just an easier way to install ROS on pcDuino?

P.S: Here is a link for those who havent heard pcDuino before: http://www.pcduino.com/?page_id=12

P.S 2: I believe it will be more helpful if I posted this on ros answers page, but it does not allow new site users to provide links. So, here I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/UbuntuARM is OK, just need to do a little modification, which you can follow http://yuanboshe.github.io/blog/2013/07/install_ros_groovy_in_pcduino.html. It's written in Chinese, but I think you can understand.

Comment: This could be solution to all my problems, I will try that and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: That works, on a side note, you also have to add ROS_OVERRIDE ubuntu:12.04 into your ~/.bashrc file like here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_OS_OVERRIDE

Comment: thanks for @mozcelikors 's mention. and the URL is change to http://yuanboshe.github.io/blog/2013-07-install_ros_groovy_in_pcduino.html